reversing array of objects in javascript
Suppose i have an array of objects like this
const input = [{"test":1},{"test":2},{"test":3}]

I can very well do a reverse of the array objects using below code
const result = input.reverse();

This would give me the desired output
[{"test":3},{"test":2},{"test":1}]

Can someone let me know how do i do a reverse if the input is slightly modified as below newInput
const newInput = { releases: [{"test":1},{"test":2},{"test":3}] }

I want the output in same structure but reversing the releases array of objects like below
{ releases: [{"test":3},{"test":2},{"test":1}] }


If you don't want to mutate the original object then you can do const reversedReleases = newInput.releases.slice().reverse(); then const result = { releases: reversedReleases };

@ChrisG Array#toReversed()

You can call reverse on the newInput.releases array:


const newInput = { releases: [{"test":1},{"test":2},{"test":3}] }
newInput.releases.reverse();

console.log(newInput);




i was doing const modOutput = newInput.releases.reverse(). instead of this, doing just the newInput.releases.reverse() would keep the same structure. thanks
